# Boost::unordered_map with initialization list?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, initialization

Is it possible to initialize a `boost::unordered_map` with a initialization list? `-Weffc++` requires it.

I can't use a method to initialize it because I only fill the map after some processing inside the constructor. I could create an empty map inside a method and return it, but that doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

I could use a pointer too and initialize it to NULL. I'd rather not though it's better than creating the equivalent of an empty method.

Comment: What do you mean by an initialization list here? Why not just invoke its default constructor explicitly?

Comment: I don't use `Weffc++` for this reason.

Comment: I don't use `-Weffc++` because it looks like it is a "polite" way to say "F*** C++`, which of course I don't want to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just default-construct the member variable in the initialization list:

```
struct S {
    boost::unordered_map<int, int> m;

    S() : m() { }
};
```

This is enough to make `-Weffc++` shut up.

Comment: That's value-initialization, not default-initialization (§8.5/7). :-]

Comment: Right, thank you.  (I really meant _default construct_, but yes, _value initialization_ is also correct and more general.)